Problema con sincronizacion de datos con nestjs y typeorm
tardes o noches. Tengo un problema al momento de enviar los datos de una base de datos A hacia una base de datos B. Y es que, cuando hago el envió de información me da error. Muestro el error a continuación (es error en consola), lo que necesito lograr es una sincronización de datos

Como se aprecia en la imagen me conecto en la BD2. Mas no me deja insertar los datos
A continuación paso a mostrar los datos de configuración:
tfachisa.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { dataSource2 } from 'typeorm.config';
import { Tfachisa } from './entities/tfachisa.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class TfachisaService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Tfachisa)
    private readonly tfachisaRepository:Repository<Tfachisa>
  ){}

  async findAll() {
    dataSource2.initialize()
    .then(async ()=>{
      console.log("Conexion inicializada")

      const data = await this.tfachisaRepository.find()
      
      const mappedData: Array<{}> = [];
      for (const item of data){
        const mappedItem = {
          "TIPODOCU": item.TIPODOCU,
          "NUMEDOCU": item.NUMEDOCU,
          "LINENUME": item.LINENUME,
          "CODICLIE": item.CODICLIE,
          "CODIRUTA": item.CODIRUTA
        };
        mappedData.push(mappedItem)
      }

      const repository2 = dataSource2.getRepository(Tfachisa);
      for (const mappedItem of mappedData){
        await repository2.save(mappedItem);
      }
      console.log("Datos insertados con exito")

    }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log("Erro al insertar los datos en la BD", err)
    })
  }
}

typeorm.config.ts:
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm'
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'
import { config } from 'dotenv'

config()

const configService = new ConfigService();

export const dataSource2 = new DataSource({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: configService.get('DB_HOST2'),
    port: configService.get('DB_PORT2'),
    username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME2'),
    password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD2'),
    database: configService.get('DB_NAME2'),
    // entities: [
    //     "./src/*/*/*.entity.ts"
    // ],
    // migrations:["migrations/*$yarn_config_pruebatestS.ts"]
});

export const dataSource1 = new DataSource({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
    port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
    username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
    password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
    database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
})

app.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { TchiaModule } from './tchia/tchia.module';   
import { TfachisaModule } from './tfachisa/tfachisa.module';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true, envFilePath: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports:[ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'mysql',
        host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
        port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
        autoLoadEntities: true
      }),
      inject:[ConfigService],
    }),
    TchiaModule,
    TfachisaModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule { }


Toda la información y documentación que encuentro es al respecto de crear las entidades. Pero no encuentro ninguna guía para poder pasar el contenido de las tablas. Ya que lo que intento hacer es una sincronización de datos. Agradezco a quienes hayan pasado por aquí y quienes me den un aparte o índice de algo

Creo que te falto el mensaje de error.

Tienes razón. Una disculpa, no se en que momento abre borrado la imagen con el error
